# Mapped object assignment: `string` not assignable to `key in N`

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Why does the following not work:

```
function foo<N extends string>(name: N): { [key in N]: string } {
    return { [name]: 'foo' };
}
```

The error given is:

```
Type { [x: string]: string } is not assignable to { [key in N: string }
```

Even though `name` inside the function body is definitely of type `N`, and so feels like the compiler should be able to work out that the object literal is of the right type.

This feels so trivial that it feels like I'm missing something. Sorry if this is a common question, but part of my problem is that I also don't know what terms to Google for to describe it.

Comment: For clarity, what I'm trying to achieve is statically knowing that the key assigned to `name` is in the return object.

Comment: Hmm I can't seem to see anything wrong with your code. My guess is that this is either a bug or design limitation in the compiler. You could open an issue on the TypeScript Github and see if somebody there knows what's up. In the meantime I would probably just cast the return value to `any`.